# CMD: Which drive letter is my Android Device using?

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, cmd, usb-mass-storage

I have a batch script where I copy a file to my Android Phone's SD card.  I have mass storage turned on, so I am just using the `cp` command rather than an `adb push`...

The problem is if I have my flash drive plugged in at the same time, the drive letter is changed.  Also, if I moved to a computer that had a different drive setup, I would be in the same pickle...

**How can I detect which drive letter my phone is using?**

Comment: Why won't you use `ADB PUSH` since it doesn't depend on hardware, only the phone being connected and a root shell.

Comment: @user4317867 I wanted to make my script more portable...  I could use it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the serial number of your Android Device and compare with all the serial numbers of the mass storage devices on your computer.  For example running:

```
for /f "tokens=5" %A in ('dir C:^|findstr /i /c:"Volume Serial Number"') do if %A==00CC-CEF9 echo This is the drive
```

Will put the serial number into %A so you can compare it with the serial number of your Android Device.

Comment: So if volume serial number == 00CC-CEF9 then it is an android device? A little more of an explanation would be nice. :) And btw: your if statement just echos out...

Comment: That for MY USB card. All cards have a serial number. Do a Dir of yours' to see your serial number.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your answer. As it stands, your answer is incomplete. Also, you're only checking to see if C: is the android device, so you really aren't answering the question at all.

Comment: >Will put the serial number into %A so you can compare it

Comment: That's not a coherent sentence.

Comment: No it's a quote from my answer.

Comment: I tried to make your answer clearer with an edit.  I think that it is what you were trying to say...